# Post owner made an edit identical to my suggestion, causing the suggestion to be rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I had suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9584138).

But as it turns out, the OP, instead of approving it, edited his own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700322/cant-close-the-ouput-stream#32700322) by **exactly replicating what I had suggested**. Hence my edit was rejected by Community saying, "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit".

Should the Community not check that what I had suggested was exactly what OP did in his edit, and thus instead of rejecting my edit the Community should actually approve it?

Comment: Rejections due to conflicting edits don't actually hurt you any, so how would this be helpful? What would this fix other than making you feel better about the conflict? (In other words, perhaps try to sell _why_ this behavior should be changed more. You're suggesting editors getting +2 rep for an edit conflict- Why should that be the case? How would this improve the site?)

Comment: I don't mind if a suggested edit gets rejected. But the point here is that what I had suggested was exactly replicated and *that* led my edit to be rejected.

Comment: And in some situations, it just happens that you and the OP had the same idea and they were just slower about it. Yes, in this situation it looks like the OP didn't understand how suggested edits work, but that happens. It's an edge case, and I'd imagine a decently rare enough one that you really should tell us why this would be worth developer time to implement.

Comment: Got your point Kendra. Thanks. It is a rare case and not worth wasting the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation is currently very clear and straight forward: The edits of the OP always wins.

Your case is a corner case where the OP follows your suggestion. I have had cases where the OP edits to make the post worse, so I can start re-applying my changes. But I have also rejected edits to my own posts where editors miss the point.

As this would probably only happen in a few cases per day I don't think we should spend developer time on it. Just be aware that the OP can overrule your edit, specially if the post is active and/or commented on.

In rare cases where an OP keeps editing in an awful way I leave a comment where I ask the OP to hold back on editing for a while so I can get my edit in. But that is only if it is clear that the OP is struggling with the markup.

In the other cases just shrug and move on.

Answer (score -7):

Editing is more than indenting code OP. Simple as that, If your edit didn't help the question to become more clear then it's an irrelevant edit. Code formatting from OP wasn't "perfect" but it was still readable. So don't hold a grudge for something so futile. Edits are to make a question more clear so we can have a better understanding of what OP needs.

Comment: Indentation is often helpful to a post. Stop placing artificial lower limits on editing.

Comment: I'm not placing limits on anything, we're talking about this specific case. Indenting did nothing to make the question any better

Comment: Indenting in this case made the question easier to read. Did it take the question from _"what is this garbled trash?"_ to _"oh wow this is so incredibly clear I can see the next question through it!"_? No. Did it make it easier and faster to read? Yes. Under current editing "guidelines" it would then be an okay edit. Could the OP have edited anything else in the question? Not really anything worthwhile. In that case, the edit stands as an okay one.

Comment: I see your point @Kendra but try to understand mine as well, if it was a piece of code that was, lets say, 40 lines long and complex statements, then yes of course it would be a major headache to try to read it without any indentation. There's no way I can deny that. But we're talking about a piece of code that it's not that hard to read, indentation or no indentation.

Comment: As I said, it didn't take the question from "trash" to "treasure" by any means, but it does make it does still improve the readability. Edits that improve the readability of a post are generally considered decent/good edits. That's what I was trying to relay in my last comment, and I think I missed that point. Yes, it didn't take it from unreadable to readable, but it made it slightly more readable, even if it's a short block of code.

Comment: No no, I totally get you @Kendra did not mean any disrespect.

Comment: Didn't think you did, just wanted to make sure I was clear that any sort of improvement to the post is considered a good improvement. (Although I should side note that some reviewers are still in the "too minor" mindset, and will reject anything that doesn't fix every little thing with a post. Hard to change habit and all that.)

Comment: That's the point I wanted to reach @Kendra , Everyone has had their fair share of rejected edits. If OP rejected your edit and edited it himself with your same edits *so what?* be happy SO noticed his mistakes and now his question is clearer. No need to make a fuzz about getting an edit rejected.